# SSL connection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, security, ssl

Is it possible to establish an SSL connection from a JavaScript? 
Or directly in Phonegap? I don't find any information about that.

Comment: JS can't establish standard sockets. It can make HTTPS requests, which use SSL, and there's websockets that run on TOP of an http connection (and can also use https). But otherwise, there's no `socket_open()` type call in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading behind the lines, it sounds like you're having trouble making a request over SSL with Phonegap. Phonegap does not allow secure requests to a web service that has a self signed cert.

Comment: Could you please give me a prove that phonegap doesn't allow secure request? Thanks

Comment: I've been unable to find a source as of yet, but this is my experience with Phonegap. I found that I couldn't connect over ssl to a test api endpoint with a self signed cert, it needed to use http. As soon as I pointed to the Production endpoint(cert authority signed) with https it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, at least not if you're talking about client-side Javascript (as opposed to something like node.js).  However, as the otehr comment noted, HTTPS used SSL as the underlying connection, so if the URL is HTTPS then you're using SSL.

Comment: Do remember that for AJAX in the browser the same-origin-policy limits requests to use the same protocol the page was served in