# Sencha Touch - Native deployment - SSL

Tags: mobile, extjs, https, proxy, sencha-touch

I'm trying to sort out the authentication dilemma. I deploy Sencha Touch application to the phone using PhoneGap, and now I need to be able to retrieve data using Ext.data.proxy.Rest(http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest) across from HTTPS secured web service.
I'm not yet at the stage to do the testing, but am wondering about possible implications with this approach. Is it pretty straightforward or are there some hidden dangers to look out for?

Apparently [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158604/ssl-connection-in-javascript) question says that if SSL is authority signed, then there's no problem, but is there anything else to look out for?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written both PhoneGap and Sencha mobile sites, but never an app that uses both, so take this advice for what it's worth.  I don't anticipate that this is a problem.  I've done ajax calls from PhoneGap using https before without a problem.

The only real issue I've ever run across is related to how we set up our QA environment.  We self sign https certificates and Android really doesn't like that.  In production or with a proper cert, it works fine though.

So I think you are ok, I don't believe Sencha's store/proxy code does anything unusual, it should just be plain ajax.

Comment: Thanks Todd, you're my champ!